# Why is this query not returning a result?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have an Access table named `Table1`, which has a field named `FieldA`. `FieldA` had a Data Type of Text.

`FieldA` does contain the value 010005.

When I run the query, it doesn't find a match. If I run a query within Access, it does find the value.

```
OleDbConnection conn = null;
OleDbDataReader reader = null;

conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\\\\server\\folder\\mydatabase.accdb");
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldA = @p1", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = "010005";
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

dataGridView1.DataSource = reader;
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

EDIT: This worked, and is what I ended up using:

```
OleDbConnection conn = null;
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\\\\server\\folder\\mydatabase.accdb");
conn.Open();

string theValue = "010005";
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Table 1 where FieldA = '{0}'", theValue);

OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);

ada.Fill(dataTable1);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;
```

Comment: is it the single quotes on the @p1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a number to the parameter, so the value will be converted to the string `"10005"`, not `"010005"`.

Assign it as a string to the parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = "010005";
```

Also, you need to remove the apostrophes around the parameter, otherwise it won't recognise it as a parameter and look for the string `"@p1"` instead:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldA = @p1", conn);
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. I've updated my code w/ your suggestion, but the query still fails to find 010005 in the table. I've triple checked that the value does exist, and the table name is correct.

Comment: @JeffBrady: Make a test by putting the value directly in the query: `"Select * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldA = '010005'"`. If that works, then you know that there is something wrong with how you use the parameter, otherwise it's simply not there and you might for example be looing in the wrong database.

Comment: I tried that, and still returns no results. I'm expecting dataGridView1 to show the result .. hopefully that's correct in my code.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted this answer, as the quotes around the parameter was part of my problem. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `@p1` since you quoted it

Use this instead:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldA = @p1", conn);
```

Comment: thank you .. i've dropped the quotes around the parameter, and also added quotes to the value per @Guffa's suggestion above. However, it still isn't finding a result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are trying to use named parameter with OleDb which I do not believe is supported.

Detail on how to do it instead:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to [`Prepare()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the command after you've add the parameters to the command for the first time and prior to executing it:

```
OleDbCommand command    = new OleDbCommand(null, rConn);

// Create and prepare an SQL statement.
command.CommandText = "insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) values (@id, @desc)" ;
command.Parameters.Add ( "@id", id) ;
command.Parameters.Add ( "@desc", desc) ;
command.Prepare() ;  // Calling Prepare after having set the Commandtext and parameters.
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Change parameter values and call ExecuteNonQuery.
command.Parameters[0].Value = 21;
command.Parameters[1].Value = "mySecondRegion";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Once it's been properly [`Prepared()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you don't need to do that again (unless you change the parameters proper (rather than just their values).